# What I use the following data format with area chart in Google Chart tools?

Tags: google-visualization

I have been using Area Chart for one of my project. I want the area chart to show full grid lines, and come to find out that it will only show if you have number or date data on major axis. Well I want year on major axis. But putting year as number, display that with number format. Something like this... 2005 displays 2005.00 .

I have found out by going through documentation that data can be passed in this format - {v:2005, f:'2005'}. But this is not working when I pass the value in this format using google.visualization.arrayToDataTable().

json data I was trying to pass on has format something like this -

```
[["Years", "sales"],[{v:2005, f:'2005'}, 52450],[{v:2006, f:'2006'}, 63457]]
```

But the chart is not coming up... :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `{v:2005,f:'2005'}` trick, you can't use `ArrayToDataTable`, you need to define the DataTable somewhat differently. You can see a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14818429/google-chart-arraytodatatable-formatted-value-not-working/14824662#14824662):

**Not Working DataTable:**

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['Category', 'Amount'],
['Food', {v:5595.819984, f:'5.595,82'}], 
['Home', {v:1890.530002, f:'1.890,53'}], 
['Mail', {v:8.380000, f:'8,38'}], 
['Train', {v:564.899998, f:'564,90'}], 
['Photo', {v:959.119995, f:'959,12'}], 
['Lego', {v:428.760004, f:'428,76'}],
```

**Working DataTable:**

```
var data = google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Category');
data.addColumn('number', 'Amount');
data.addRows([
['Food', {v:5595.819984, f:'5.595,82'}], 
['Home', {v:1890.530002, f:'1.890,53'}], 
['Mail', {v:8.380000, f:'8,38'}], 
['Train', {v:564.899998, f:'564,90'}], 
['Photo', {v:959.119995, f:'959,12'}], 
['Lego', {v:428.760004, f:'428,76'}],
]);
```